# Please help me understand the problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Sheldon Ross's A First Course in Probability, Chapter 3, Problem 3.76:
Consider an unending sequence of independent trials, where each trial is equally likely to result in any of the outcomes 1, 2, or 3. Given that outcome  3 is the last of the three outcomes to occur, find the conditional probability that
(a)the first trial results is outcome 1;
(b)the first two trials both result in outcome 1.

I can't understand what does it mean,I think there are no influence about the first trial results and the last three outcomes,because it says they are independent trials.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble understanding it too, but looking up the solution resolved the ambiguity.  It means that in the results from the unending sequence of trials both of the outcomes $1$ and $2$ occur before the outcome $3$ does.  This implies that neither of the first two trials can result in outcome $3$.

Comment: You mean the sequence could be like {1,2,3......} and {2,1,3....}?It couldn't be {3,1,2.....},{3,2,1....},{2,3,1....},{1,3,2....}

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

I explain the first part $(a)$. You have to calculate a conditional probability as $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

The given event is $B$. This is where you have the sequence $\color{green}x\color{blue}{xx...xxx}\color{red}3 \ \ (\textrm{seq. I})$, where $x$ is a $1$ or a $2$. The event $A$ occurs, if the first trial results in 1. Thus the event $A\cap B$ is  the sequence $\color{green}1\color{blue}{xx...xxx}\color{red}3 \ \ (\textrm{seq. II})$.

So you need to calculate the probability of getting sequence $\textrm{II}$ when sequence $\textrm{I}$ has already been given.

Comment: Each trial is equally likely to result in any of the outcomes 1, 2, or 3,why x can't be 3?

Comment: @Toby_Huang The outcome 3 is the last of the three outcomes. The outcomes before the (first) 3 must be an 1 or a 2

Answer (score 1):

Let random variables $X,Y,Z$ denote the *first trial* in which these respective outcomes occur.

---

The condition is that the first occurrence of outcome 3 is after the first occurrence of the other two outcomes.

$$\{X<Z\} \cap \{Y<Z\}~=~\{X<Y<Z\}\cup\{Y<X<Z\}$$

---

The event of the first problem is that the outcome 1 first occurs in the first trial: $\{X=1\}$.  So you must evaluate the conditional probability:

$$P_1:=\mathsf P(X=1\mid X<Z, Y<Z)$$

---

The event of the second problem is that the outcome 1 first occurs in the first trial, while both other outcomes first occur after trial 2: $\{X=1\}\cap \{2<Y\}\cap \{2<Z\}$ . So you must evaluate the conditional probability:

$$P_2:=\mathsf P(X=1, 2<Y, 2<Z\mid X<Z, Y<Z)$$

---

Use Bayes' Rule and arguments about symmetry to evaluate these conditional probabiltities

Comment: The condition is that the first occurrence of outcome 3 is after the first occurrence of the other two outcomes.Thank you!I think I understand what is the problem says,it means after 1,2 appear,then 3 could appear,is it right?

Comment: Yes, @Toby_Huang .  To be clear: some sequence of outcomes 1 and 2 appear (at least one of each) before the first outcome 3.